# It this way of using callbacks and parameters correct?

Tags: javascript, callback, parameter-passing

I am currently learning `callbacks` and I am not sure if the below way of using them, especially when it comes to the `parameter- passing`
    of the callbacks `showSuccessMessage` and `showErrorMessage` to `signupUser` completely `optimal`? I am confused also when you can `name` callbacks/ parameters in a `general versus concrete` way ?

Could you optimize my code if it´s not correct and explain me, please ?

```
     // GLOBAL ARRAY for storing any DATA from the SERVER
     var ajDataFromServer = [];

      // Main ajax function using callback for posting data to the server
      function postAjax( sUrl , frmData, callback ){
                  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        var ajDataFromServer = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        callback( ajDataFromServer, showSuccessMessage, showErrorMessage );
                    }
                }           
                  ajax.open( "POST", sUrl , true );
                  var jFrm = new FormData( frmData );
                  ajax.send( jFrm )                 
                }


/************************************************************************/
/************************************************************************/
/************************************************************************/


      // DO the SIGNUP, POST data to the SERVER with AJAX

      btnSignupForm.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          postAjax( "api_signup_users.php", frmSignup, signupUser );
      });

      function signupUser( ajUserDataFromServer, showSuccessMessage, showErrorMessage  ) {

                  if ( ajUserDataFromServer.status == "ok" ) {

                      //console.log( "SIGNUP SUCCESFULL" );
                      pageLogin.style.display = "flex";
                      pageSignup.style.display = "none";
                      showSuccessMessage( "Account succesfully created - Signup please" );

                  } else {

                      //console.log( "SIGNUP FAIL - TRY AGAIN" );
                      pageViewProducts.style.display = "none";
                      pageLogin.style.display = "none";
                      pageSignup.style.display = "flex";
                      showErrorMessage( "Signup Failed - Try again" );
                  }
              }

      /************************************************************************/
      /************************************************************************/
      /************************************************************************/


      function showSuccessMessage ( sSuccessMessage ) {
        var alblMessages = document.getElementsByClassName( "lblMessage" );
          for ( var i = 0; i < alblMessages.length; i++ ) { 
            alblMessages[i].innerHTML = sSuccessMessage.fontcolor("#549839");
          }   
      }

      /************************************************************************/
      /************************************************************************/
      /************************************************************************/


      function showErrorMessage (sErrorMessage) {
        var alblMessages = document.getElementsByClassName( "lblMessage" );
          for ( var i = 0; i < alblMessages.length; i++ ) { 
            alblMessages[i].innerHTML = sErrorMessage.fontcolor("red");
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you have "different" variables that have the same names (`showSuccessMessage/showErrorMessage`) in different scopes (which is totally valid and can be useful to identify arguments when nesting a lot of function calling levels, but it can introduce a confusion when learning), this looks correct.

The only downside i see in the design is that `postAjax` is calling `showSuccessMessage` and `showErrorMessage` globally, so you can't choose the way message are displayed when you call `postAjax`. Again, this is perfectly valid to have global calls to these functions if `postAjax` will never use other functions to pass to `signupUser`, but this makes passing these as arguments to this function useless, as `signupUser` could call them directly from globals too. The single case where this design could be useful: if you have other functions than `postAjax` that can call `signupUser` with different message handlers.

So it actually depends rather on how you plan to use these functions, if you have a function that could call different callbacks, a callback parameter is justified, or else it can just call these functions directly.

If you want to be able to control the message display when you call the first function (`postAjax`), you should change the code a little. the more generic way to control this, that can allow more possibilities, is to use an anonymous callback function, and that the only parameter passed to the callback is the data:

```
  // Main ajax function using callback for posting data to the server
  function postAjax( sUrl , frmData, callback ){
      /*code*/
      callback( ajDataFromServer );
      /*code*/                
  }

  //using first set of message functions
  btnSignupForm.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      postAjax( "api_signup_users.php", frmSignup, function(data){
          signupUser(data, showSuccessMessage, showErrorMessage);
      });
  });
  //using second set for another button
  btnSignupForm2.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      postAjax( "api_signup_users.php", frmSignup, function(data){
          signupUser(data, showSuccessMessage2, showErrorMessage2);
      });
  });

  function signupUser( ajUserDataFromServer, showSuccessMessage, showErrorMessage  ) {
      /*code*/
  }

  function showSuccessMessage ( sSuccessMessage ) {
      /*code*/
  }
  function showErrorMessage (sErrorMessage) {
      /*code*/
  }

  function showSuccessMessage2 ( sSuccessMessage ) {
      /*code*/
  }
  function showErrorMessage2 (sErrorMessage) {
      /*code*/
  }
```

**Edit** following comments:
When talking about a default value, it was more for being to use your "global" message functions, but with the possibility to redefine some callback functions. Again, this is not necessary in your case, still this is good to know how to do it:

```
  // Main ajax function using callback for posting data to the server
  // it still sends only the data to its callback
  function postAjax( sUrl , frmData, callback ){
      /*code*/
      callback( ajDataFromServer );
      /*code*/                
  }

  //using default set of message functions:
  //just pass the function to use as you did in original code, no need for
  //an anonymous function. This function will be passed only the data (cf postAjax code),
  //and because 2 arguments are missing in its definition, it will use its default ones:
  btnSignupForm.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      postAjax( "api_signup_users.php", frmSignup, signupUser);
  });

  //redefining the message callbacks:
  //the trick here is to use an anonymous function like in precedent code.
  //It is this anonymous function that will be called by postAjax. But now
  //we manually make the call to signupUser inside, so we can decide to use
  //another set of message callbacks by filling the 2nd and 3rd parameters:
  btnSignupForm2.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      postAjax( "api_signup_users.php", frmSignup, function(data) {
          signupUser(data, showSuccessMessage2, showErrorMessage2);
      });
  });

  function signupUser( ajUserDataFromServer, showSuccessMessageParam, showErrorMessageParam ) {
      //fixed default values for the message functions:
      if(undefined === showSuccessMessageParam){
          showSuccessMessageParam = showSuccessMessage;
      }
      if(undefined === showErrorMessageParam){
          showErrorMessageParam = showErrorMessage;
      }
      /*code*/
      //rest of the code will use the param variables:
      if(isSuccess){
          showSuccessMessageParam('...');
      }else{
          showErrorMessageParam('...');
      }
  }

  function showSuccessMessage ( sSuccessMessage ) {
      /*code*/
  }
  function showErrorMessage (sErrorMessage) {
      /*code*/
  }

  function showSuccessMessage2 ( sSuccessMessage ) {
      /*code*/
  }
  function showErrorMessage2 (sErrorMessage) {
      /*code*/
  }
```

Comment: thank you. very nice explanation it perfectly clarifies my doubts.

Comment: my plan is that postAjax is the single main function ( for posting data ) that will call many other functions for instance `signupUser`, `updateUser` , `deleteUser` but  with the same message display. So what I have just understand from your explanation is that then I don´t need parameters for the message displays. Am I right ?

Comment: basically yes, these functions can call message functions directly if not meant to change. But it also depends on you wanting or not to be able to re-use these functions for another project. What can also be done in this perspective is to still have these 2 parameters, but with default values to the message functions you currently have. You then could be able to call them with or without the parameters. However, my advice is to start simple and do this only when needed.

Comment: I have added an update below according to your idea. check out if is right.

Comment: @codeDragon updated the answer with fix default values for the messages, so that `signupUser` can be used with or without message callback parameters

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this you were thinking of @Kaddath , now having fCallback as a default value for the messages, later on they can be reused. I think is enough to have only one parameter since is an if / else case.

```
// Main ajax function using callback for posting data from the server
  function postAjax( sUrl, callback) {
           /*code*/
           callback( ajDataFromServer, fCallback );
           /*code*/

  }

  // DO the SIGNUP, POST data to the SERVER with AJAX

  btnSignupForm.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      postAjax( "api_signup_users.php", frmSignup, signupUser );
  });

  function signupUser( ajUserDataFromServer, fCallback ) {
                  /*code*/
                  showSuccessMessage( "Account succesfully created - Signup please" );

              } else {
                  /*code*/
                  showErrorMessage( "Signup Failed - Try again" );
              }
          }

  /************************************************************************/
  /************************************************************************/
  /************************************************************************/


  function showSuccessMessage ( sSuccessMessage ) {
       /*code*/  
  }

  /************************************************************************/
  /************************************************************************/
  /************************************************************************/


  function showErrorMessage (sErrorMessage) {
        /*code*/
      }
  }
```

Comment: this won't work for different reasons, first, `fCallback` is undefined in `postAjax`, and the structure is a bit off, as as single `fCallback` inside `signupUser` won't be practical for handling two different cases (it's possible in the end, but over-complex for your case). I'll edit my answer.